# Android: Fragments: setContentView alternative

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to rewrite an existing project using `fragments` to port my application on tablet.

I'm replacing activities with `fragments`.

The problem is that I don't know what is the equivalent to `setContentView` method? Is there any way to create `Fragment's` view except rewriting `onCreateView`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the `onCreateView()` method you can return the view of your fragment as follows :

```
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_tab, container, false); 
}
```

Comment: Should note that this is:
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_tab, container, false);
    }

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you cannot use `onCreateView`. But here is what you can do.

Create `LinearLayout` object, save it as `mRooLayout` member field and return it from `onCreateView`. Here is how you can implement `setContentView`:

```
void setFragmentContentView(View view)
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    mRootLayout.removeAllViews();
    mRootLayout.addView(view, layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I load view in async. So when onCreateView is being called by the OS actual view in not ready yet. I'll try your code, thanks

Comment: Do you mean that I can call onCreateView in any moment? or what should I call to make my fragment recreate its view?

Comment: No, you cannot call `onCreateView`. Well you can, but this will not have any effect and will most likely mess everything up in your fragment (if you save references to views in this function). This function should only be called by OS.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I meant what should I call to make OS call that method?

Comment: You can't do anything. Its life-cycle callback. Just re-organize the way you handle views. You can use my answer as starting point.